# Scheme #<void> when writing a function

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to write a function that will insert a number into an already existing tree. So far I have

```
(define (make-tree v left right)
  (list v left right))

(define (value t)
  (car t))

(define(left t)
  (cadr t))

(define(right t)
  (caddr t))

(define new-tree (make-tree 10
                            (make-tree 6
                                       (make-tree 3 null null)
                                       (make-tree 7 null null))
                            (make-tree 11
                                       (make-tree 3 null null)
                                       (make-tree 12 null null))))



(define(my-tree initial-tree)
  (let ((tree initial-tree))
    (define (element? f)
      (define(sub-element? f t)
        (begin
          (cond
           ((null? t) #f)
           ((eq? f (value t)) #t)
           ((> f (value t)) (sub-element? f (right t)))
           ((< f (value t)) (sub-element? f (left t))))))
      (sub-element? f tree))
    (define (insert f)
      (define (sub-insert f t)
        (begin
         (set! tree
               (cond
                ((null? t) (make-tree f null null))
                ((eq? f (value t)) t)
                ((< f (value t)) (make-tree (value t) (sub-insert f (left t)) (right t)))
                ((> f (value t)) (make-tree (value t) (left t) (sub-insert f (right t))))))))
      (sub-insert f tree)
      tree)
    (lambda (method)
      (cond
       ((eq? method 'insert) insert)
       ((eq? method 'element?) element?)))))
```

The resulting output is `(10 #<void> (11 (3 () ()) (12 () ())))`
when I do `((test-tree 'insert)5)`. I was wondering why this was the case.

Comment: The code you posted is clearly incomplete (it's missing several closing parentheses, at least.)

Comment: this is part of a much larger function. the other part works, and I didn't want to put more on there than was needed for ease of reading. I was just wondering why this would result in #<void> or more generally why that occurs at all.

Comment: What function is returning `#<void>`? Without that information, how can we figure out the problem? `#<void>` return values arise through the same case as any other return values: if the expression(s) in tail position return `#<void>`.

Comment: ((test-tree 'insert)5) is the test case. which utilizes the function (insert f), is returning the output that I wrote down above.

Comment: Then you should provide all the code for `(insert f)`. Right now, the code you post is interrupted in the middle of a `cond`...

Comment: I've posted the full function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `sub-insert` is the return value of `set!`, and Racket's `set!` returns nothing, or `#<void>`.

Don't modify `tree` during the recursion.
Instead, first build the result, then update `tree`:

```
(define (insert f)
  (define (sub-insert t)
    (cond
      [(null? t) (make-tree f null null)]
      [(equal? f (value t)) t]
      [(< f (value t)) (make-tree (value t) (sub-insert (left t)) (right t))]
      [else            (make-tree (value t) (left t) (sub-insert (right t)))]))

  (set! tree (sub-insert tree))
  tree)
```

The rest of the code can stay the same.

I can recommend that you start your testing with smaller and simpler test cases.
You would have found the same problem with a one-node tree, which is much easier to reason about and debug.
(Note that your test tree isn't a valid search tree, so it's not a very good test case.  )

Comment: And even moving the `set!` out of `insert` completely would be better and `insert` could potentially be used on more than one global tree.